# what "rejection" means in MSVC inline asm

Tags: assembly, visual-c++, inline-assembly

I found a code which was published at 2008, there is a command I can't understand

what is `rejection`?

It's not a x86 assembly instruction, right?

```
__declspec ( naked )  DWORD  Hash ( char  * passwd)  
{  
    __asm  
    {  
    mov esi, [esp + 4]  

    xor eax, eax  
    push ecx   
    push esi   
    push edx  
   .
   .
   .
    jnz $ L1  
    pop edx   
    pop esi   
    pop ecx  
    rejection  
    }  
}
```

Comment: No its not, I'm guessing its a macro that is being expanded to something more sensible.

Comment: It could instead be a label name.  Is there a `jne rejection` anywhere?  I think MSVC inline-asm syntax allows labels with a `:`.  If it is a label, it would be much better style to use `rejection:`, because that would have made it obvious.

Comment: Sorry guys,I found the problem, it's quite stupid.....

Comment: Please post the answer as an answer (click "answer your own question"), not as an edit to the question.  And BTW, that is an amusing answer.  Not what either of use were guess at all.

Comment: oh, I thought that would get some point or what, so I tried not to answer my 
own question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original website was written in Korean

Chrome try to show it in English, so `ret` was changed to `rejection`.....

Comment: Automatic website translation in browsers tend to do ridiculously stupid things. I once saw it translate input fields in Bugzilla's editable and editable-but-grayed-out fields. Disable it whenever possible.